# Percona MySQL 5.5.33 not reading my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, percona, redhat

At some point Percona MySQL on CentOS 6.4 seems to have stopped reading my.cnf, possibly after MySQL updated to 5.5.33 a few days ago.

Selection from /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                    = mysql
default-storage-engine  = InnoDB
socket                  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid_file                = /var/run/mysql.pid
symbolic-links          = 0 

# CHARACTER SET AND COLLATION #
collation-server        = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server    = utf8
init-connect            = 'SET NAMES utf8'
init-connect            = 'SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'

# DATA STORAGE AND LOGGING #
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
slow_query_log_file     = mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log          = 1 
long_query_time         = 8 
log_error               = mysql-error.log

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
max_connections         = 250
max_connect_errors      = 10000
open_files_limit        = 20000
back_log                = 100
wait_timeout            = 10800
interactive_timeout     = 600
max_allowed_packet      = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 512M
max_heap_table_size     = 64M 
query_cache_size        = 32M
thread_cache_size       = 64
```

Some output from 'mysqld --help --verbose'

```
log-error                                         mysql-error.log
slow-query-log                                    TRUE
slow-query-log-file                               mysql-slow.log
max-connections                                   250
max-heap-table-size                               67108864
```

Ok that seems good, matches my config. How about logging into mysql and doing some SHOW VARIABLES:

```
log_error   /var/lib/mysql/hostname.err
log_slow_queries    OFF
slow_query_log_file /var/lib/mysql/hostname-slow.log
max_connections 151
max_heap_table_size 16777216
```

Huh, well that ain't right. Slow log is off, error log has the wrong name, connection and heap sizes are wrong, and the server collation is wrong as well.

Processes running

```
root     23533     1  0 12:32 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/hostname.pid
mysql    23624 23533 91 12:32 pts/3    01:05:32 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/hostname.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/hostname.pid
```

I see the error log listed in the process has the wrong name right off the bat. I've tried manually restarting mysql from /etc/init.d, via 'service mysql restart', via restarting the entire server. Nothing seems to get MySQL to read the conf.

Maybe something is breaking when mysqld_safe spins up a mysql instance? No problems reported in the error log when the server starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580331/mysql-how-to-determine-which-config-file-is-being-used

Ahh, i need 30 characters in post.

Comment: stat("/etc/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5209, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/my.cnf", O_RDONLY)           = 3    (run mysqld directly and the my.cnf is obeyed, as noted in my OP, but when run as a system service it is not using my.cnf)

Comment: whell may be they moved config into /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: as of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12246575

Comment: i just don't have centos to investigate, look at the init script

Comment: 'my_print_defaults mysqld' does print the right values, but from the OP 'mysqld --help --verbose' prints the right values as well. It's when the server actually starts that it does NOT have the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the problem was SELinux on CentOS, and the answer was to [disable SELinux](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/how-do-i-turn-selinux-redhat-or-centos)! I couldn't find any errors in the SELinux log related to MySQL so this took quite some time to track down.

Comment: +1 the first question should always be, "what else changed?" ;-)